# Adding bootstrap in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm going to use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to build up my front end. Also I'm using JSP and JSTL

What I've read in some articles over the internet is the proper approach of adding an external javascript file should be written before the body closing tag for more optimization of the page. Now I'm trying to apply this with the bootstrap, what i did is put the `css` of the bootstrap to an external html file:

**import_header.html:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
```

which I imported to the head of the html like this:

```
<jsp:include page="import_header.html" flush="true" />
```

Now I want to do the same thing with the `js` file of the of the bootstrap and the `jQuery` lib but I don't know what is the proper way of doing this.

Comment: You mean that you want to include them in your main html file? As is `<script src="js/jquery.js">` insert right before the body closing tag?

Comment: What I did above is make an external html file where I already link all css files then I will only include 1 file in the html file. If I do what your suggesting. I have to include 4 js file every time I create a new page.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it goes. Use some of the js frameworks, and you'll have to include a dozen files. Trying to include them in an external like you did with your css files seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

that's the recommended way, how to place them:

e.g. footer.html

```
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap-2.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="myOwn.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would say 'recommended', rather than 'correct'. Traditionally, scripts were loaded in the <head> section. Nowadays, JS sees heavy usage and hence the page is given time to load while the JS code is loading and running, hence placing them towards the end.