# Bootstrap navigation bar collapse not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I really could not be able to find out what is the issue to not to work my navigation bar collapse. Please can you show me what is the error for this issue. I have added jQuery and glyphicons to the navigation. Are these causes for this issue.

```
<!--Navigation Start-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">Senid Computer</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="home.html">

                            <center><i class="fa fa-home medium"></i>

                            </center>Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown" id="li1">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

                            <center><i class="fa fa-laptop medium"></i>

                            </center>Laptops <span class="caret"></span>

                        </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="id1-dd">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="laptops/laptop_apple.html">Apple</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="laptops/laptop_hp.html">Hewlett Packard</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="laptops/laptop_dell.html">Dell</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="laptops/laptop_asus.html">Asus</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="desktop.html">

                            <center><i class="fa fa-desktop medium text-inverse"></i>

                            </center>Desktops</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="accessories.html" class="nav-ele-color">

                            <center><i class="fa fa-gamepad medium nav-ele-color"></i>

                            </center>Accessories</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="contact_us.html">

                            <center><i class="fa fa-phone medium text-inverse"></i>

                            </center>Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="login_main"><span id="login_main_p">Login  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></span></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" id="login_div">
                                <form id="formLogin" class="form container-fluid">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="uname">User Name:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" placeholder="User Name" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_login" placeholder="Password" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="javascript:login()" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Its a common problem usually due to the order of your script int he header.

Comment: so what is the solution for that?

Comment: You have to have jQuery and place it before Bootstrap JS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331210/adding-bootstrap-in-html

Comment: Ohh Thats worked Thanks for the help you guys.

Comment: Keep in mind that you should always place jQuery First

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site Name</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-medium"></i> Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
   </div>
     </nav>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit?

Comment: To make the collapse function work on a bootstrap navbar, place <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar"> before you start your menu items. And then end the tag after the menu items are complete.